# Valores predertimanos para Mysql XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Instale xampp para Linux mint y cambie el nombre de usuario y la password, y ya no me acuerdo de ninguna de las dos, y esto es un problema porque al tratar de entrar a phpmyadmin me salta lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desintale xampp primero escribiendo en la consola `rm -rf /opt/lampp` luego lo volvi a instalar y lo volvi a desintalar pero esta vez ejecutando el archivo **unistall** que viene con xampp.

Como puedo volver a los valores predertimanos o como puedo modificar el usuario y la password? he intentado de todo pero no he podido resolverlo.

Comment: Puedes restaurar las credenciales por defecto ([mira aquí](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/75002)). Y para la próxima, no pongas contraseñas que luego olvides.

Comment: Hola, vaya lio. Intenta esto: [MySQL reset root password](https://www.a2hosting.es/kb/developer-corner/mysql/reset-mysql-root-password). Y por cierto, imagino que por el desespero, pero escribiste: *predertimanos*, cuando es *predeterminados*. Además, respasa [ask]. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, ya resolvi